# How to curve fit multiple y vals for single x value?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to use numpy to curve fit (polyfit) a data set I have - it's multiple y vals for discrete x vals, i.e.:
`data = [[2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 4]]`
where the index is x, and the arrays are the y vals.
I tried the average/median of each array, but I get the feeling that's ignoring a lot of useful data.

TLDR:
Need to fit a curve to this scatter plot:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `np.polyfit` and vary the polynomial degree adequately.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I can't find any options to pass in anything other than a y array that is the same shape as the x array. That is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You could try and use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit. This has a parameter `sigma` which accepts the covariance matrix of `y`-errors. That way the fit would use more of the information contained in your data set.

Comment: Looks like a series of [beta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).  You could fit each discrete `x` to an `a,b` paramemter in y and fit the mean values with weight paramemters of inverse variance.  But that's more a question for [stats.se].  Maybe ask there and if you have implementation problems you can ask here.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't `polyfit` this data at all, as it seems bounded on `[0,1]` in `y` which you can't enforce with `polyfit`.  Probably want to fit to some inverse trig function.

Answer (score 3):

You could flatten your data out:

```
x = []
y = []
for i,ydata in enumerate(data):
    x += [i]*len(ydata)
    y += ydata
```

Now you can fit to `x` and `y` and it will account for all points in the set.